# Ideals with certain properties

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, ho.history-overview, notation

I recently isolated the following definition, which I believe it should have appeared somewhere.

Let $\kappa$ be a cardinal, and let $X$ be a set with $\kappa^+\leq |X|$.

**Definition**: An ideal
$\mathcal I\subseteq \mathcal P(\mathcal P_{\kappa^+}(X))$ is called a B-ideal if the following hold.

1. for every $x\in X$, $\{A\in \mathcal P_{\kappa^+}(X):x\in A    \}$ is not in $\mathcal I$.
2. $(\mathcal I^{+},\subseteq)$ has a $\kappa$-closed dense subset which means there is $\mathcal D\subseteq \mathcal I^+$ such that for every $A\in\mathcal I^+$, there is $B\in\mathcal D$ with $B\subseteq A$, and that every decreasing sequence in $\mathcal D$ of length less than $\kappa$ has a lower bound.

In my definition **B** stands for Baumgartner.

My question is if such an ideal has a name in the litrature?

Comment: @GabeGoldberg I clarified the notion of closedness.

Comment: I don’t think it has a name, but the hypothesis appears in the literature.  See for example, Proposition 5.22 in Foreman’s chapter of the Handbook of Set Theory.

Comment: A very similar hypothesis also appears as Lemma 4.5 in my thesis.

Comment: Thank you @MonroeEskew .